# Which adservice pay for impression?

Tags: admob, google-play-services

I have 2 app which has admob ad-service.
both apps  have currently 100+ avarage installs.
my avarage impression is 250+ per day eventhough my earning is 0$.

i want to know is there any adservice which pay for impression rather than clicks
plz post the links and api guide.

Answer (score 0):

Most services will provide some revenue for impressions, but not when you are getting 250 impressions a day. As you start getting beyond about 100,000 impressions a day you will start to see some uptick.